# Freezing ESP8266 after 4-8h

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, neopixel, watchdog

Build my own 'Artnet to WS2812b Neopixel' boxes for lighting in a club. Working fine. I have 20 stripes with 50 pxls each. One ESP8266(NodeMCU) is feeding 6 stripes, so it gets 2 DMX universes via Artnet. Depending on the FPS(~20-40FPS) i'm sending, thats about 200-300kbp/s constant bitrate for each of the ESPs.
Every 4-8h one of my boxes freezes randomly. No pinging possible anymore. The other boxes continue working as usual. Only chance of resetting is to disconnect the power. 
First, i thought the ESP gets to hot (installed at the clubs ceeling and the power supply is also in such a box) or the humidity is to high, but it must be a software problem (tested it in the oven, dont laugh ;)).
So why isn't the watchdog resetting? I am not able to provoke any of those freezes at home (only waiting)

The code is pretty straight forward:

1. test the leds
2. connect to wifi (if no wifi, go to 1)

Loop:

3. check UDP packets for Artnetdata
4. update the WS2812 with the fastled-lib

any ideas?

```
#define FASTLED_ESP8266_NODEMCU_PIN_ORDER
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#include <FastLED.h>

// ARTNET CODES
#define ARTNET_DATA 0x50
#define ARTNET_POLL 0x20
#define ARTNET_POLL_REPLY 0x21
#define ARTNET_PORT 6454
#define ARTNET_HEADER 17

WiFiUDP udp;

#define NUM_LEDS 50

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB leds2[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB leds3[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB leds4[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB leds5[NUM_LEDS];
CRGB leds6[NUM_LEDS];


unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
int offset=0;

uint8_t uniData[514];
uint8_t maxuni=0;
uint16_t uniSize;
uint8_t hData[ARTNET_HEADER + 1];


const char* ssid     = "*";
const char* password = "*";

IPAddress local_ip(192, 168, 0, 111);
IPAddress gateway_ip(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnet_ip(255, 255, 255, 0);

void setup() {
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  WiFi.config(local_ip, gateway_ip, subnet_ip);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
   delay(500);


delay(2000); // sanity delay
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 1, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 2, GRB>(leds2, NUM_LEDS);
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 3, GRB>(leds3, NUM_LEDS);
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 4, GRB>(leds4, NUM_LEDS);
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 5, GRB>(leds5, NUM_LEDS);
FastLED.addLeds<WS2812, 6, GRB>(leds6, NUM_LEDS);
initTest();

  }

  udp.begin(ARTNET_PORT); // Open ArtNet port
}

void loop() {

  if (udp.parsePacket()) { 
    udp.read(hData, ARTNET_HEADER+1);
    if ( hData[0] == 'A' && hData[1] == 'r') { //checking first two letters, if its Artnet data
      if ( hData[8] == 0x00 && hData[9] == ARTNET_DATA) {
      uniSize = (hData[16] << 8) + (hData[17]);
      udp.read(uniData, uniSize);

      if(hData[14]>maxuni){maxuni=hData[14];}

     switch(hData[14]+1-maxuni){

      case 0: //for each DMX universe updating the pixels
         for (int j=50; j--;){
            leds[j].setRGB(uniData[j*3+offset],uniData[j*3+1+offset],uniData[j*3+2+offset]);
          leds2[j].setRGB(uniData[j*3+150+offset],uniData[j*3+151+offset],uniData[j*3+152+offset]);
          leds3[j].setRGB(uniData[j*3+300+offset],uniData[j*3+301+offset],uniData[j*3+302+offset]);
         }
         break;

      case 1:
         for (int j=50; j--;){
           leds4[j].setRGB(uniData[j*3+offset],uniData[j*3+1+offset],uniData[j*3+2+offset]);
          leds5[j].setRGB(uniData[j*3+150+offset],uniData[j*3+151+offset],uniData[j*3+152+offset]);
          leds6[j].setRGB(uniData[j*3+300+offset],uniData[j*3+301+offset],uniData[j*3+302+offset]);
         }
         break;
     }
}
}
}

FastLED.show();
}


void initTest()
{
//only at Startup checking the LEDs, so nothing special here....}
```

Comment: disconnect the LED strip ... does it still freeze?

Comment: it could be power fluctuations, maybe a fat cap from gnd to vcc would help. or a memory leak, keep an eye on the heap size and see if it ticks down over time. Worst case, work on getting them to boot faster, then reboot every few hours.